# contenteditable получить то что вижу

Tags: javascript, html

### Решение найдено, нужно использовать elem.innerText

В div#q1 contenteditable у меня есть текст и выглядит на экране он так:

```
строка1
строка2
строка3
```

Но в коде это выглядит так:

```html
<div id="q1" contenteditable="true">
строка1
<div>строка2</div>
<div>строка3</div>
</div>
```

Иногда может так:

```html
<div id="q1" contenteditable="true">
    строка1
    <br>
    строка2
    <br>
    строка3
</div>
```

А бывает вообще **вперемешку div и br да ещё и вложенные**

Когда я делаю `document.querySelector('#q1').textContent` то получаю текст без переносов
Если я делаю `document.querySelector('#q1').innerHTML` то могу заменить все `<br>` на перенос \n
но как быть если у меня помимо br есть переносы с помощью div

Я пробовал перед и после всех div ставить br

```
div[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<br>');
div[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<br>');
```

но в этом случае получаются лишние переносы.

Есть ли способ получить именно то что вижу на экране (текст и переносы) в виде текста в js переменную? (перенос в виде \n)

---

Добавлено:
Просто я думал что есть уже готовые решения или простые способы брать то что видишь из html и это по идее должно работать не только с contenteditable но и с любым html. Вообще полная задача у меня такая: есть div contenteditable, в нём текст. У меня есть 2 поля textarea 'что заманить' и 'чем заменить' аналог ctrl+H с поддержкой текста с переносами. Я хочу чтобы этот самописный аналог ctrl+H заменял содержимое div contenteditable (сначала получал текст, потом делал замену, потом вставлял текст обратно [css стили можно терять, они не важны])

---

Первое решение, подойдёт для особых случаев:

1. нужно выделить текст в div#q1 contenteditable (с помощью createRange...)
2. получить выделенный на странице текст в переменную. Готово.

Comment: Почему contenteditable, а не textarea?

Comment: Потому что в итоге я раскрашиваю текст и меняю размер шрифта с помощью span в некоторых местах у финального текста и навешиваю там некоторые события onckick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В теории

1. Берем innerHtml и удаляем все переносы строк, которые есть сейчас через `\n`. Т.е. по сути инлайним весь хтмл в одну строку.
2. Заменяем все связки `</div><div>` на `\n`

2а) Тут еще нужно проверить наличие лишних пробелов между тегами div и предварительно избавится  от них, можно это через регулярки провернуть.

2б) Остается кейс с вложенностью, `<div>` и `</div>` по отдельности заменяем на `<br/>`

2в) Возможно получатся лишние `<br/>` в начале и в конце нашей конечной строки, избавляемся от них (можно через регулярки, можно через split)

3. Заменяем все `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br />` и тоже самое в верхнем регистре (следует учитывать разную кривую верстку) на `\n`

Так же следует учитывать, что на самих div могут быть навешены paddings и margins, соответственно в конечном варианте отступы уже не будут выглядеть также, как в исходном.

Возможно еще какие-то пограничные кейсы забыл, но тут уже действуйте по обстоятельствам

Comment: Спасибо, css  paddings и margins и не нужны, интересует только текст

Comment: А есть готовый код который сможет заменить все связки </div><div>? Или вы имеете ввиду просто заменить '</div><div>'?  Просто вроде могут быть и вложенные ('<div>текст<div>текст<div>текст</div></div></div>'), что будет с ними?

Comment: Так мы же с html работаем как со строкой, через обычный метод replace (с учетом что мы от лишних переносов и пробелов уже избавились `text = text.replace("</div><div>", "");`

Comment: Можно попробовать такой вариант, заменяем сначала все связки `</div><div>`, у нас остается кейс с вложенными дивами, каждый такой блок создает как бы новую строку, соответственно все оставшиеся `<div>` и `</div>` заменяем (по отдельности) на `<br />`

Comment: Скорректировал ответ. Есть еще какие-то кейсы ?

Comment: Спасибо, наверное так и сделаю. Просто я думал что есть уже готовые решения или простые способы брать то что видишь из html и это по идее должно работать не только с contenteditable но и с любым html.
Вообще полная задача у меня такая: есть div contenteditable, в нём текст. У меня есть 2 поля textarea 'что заманить' и 'чем заменить' аналог ctrl+H с поддержкой текста с переносами. Я хочу чтобы этот самописный аналог ctrl+H заменял содержимое div contenteditable (сначала получал текст, потом делал замену, потом вставлял текст обратно [css стили можно терять, они не важны])

Comment: Прям готовых я не встречал, хотя много работал с парсингом данных. Можно играться с регулярками, но тут будет слишком много подводных камней, и каждый нужно учитывать. Нужно изначально накладывать на функционал ограничения, какие функции он будет выполнять и с какими особенностями исходных данных сможет работать. Например, у Вас может быть вообще невалидная верстка (отсутствие закрывающих тегов, например), это уже совсем другой кейс и другая история. А ctrl+H заменяет именно набор символов, идущих подряд либо через прописанную регулярку под конкретный кейс.

Comment: Если мой основной ответ помог, прошу поставить на него галочку ;)

Comment: Ок, спасибо, пока слабо помог, но если за сегодня никто ничего лучше не предложит то поставлю. Всё дело в том что каждый браузер может делать что хочет, некоторые вообще вместо тегов div и br вставляют отсебятину. Наверное здесь вообще нужно обращать внимание на display block/inline а не на теги

Answer (score 0):

**Проблема решена!** Я хз почему сам сразу не додумался (какой же я тупой), но ещё больше удивлён что никто здесь тоже не додумался

1. нужно выделить текст в div#q1 contenteditable (с помощью createRange...)
2. получить выделенный на странице текст в переменную. Готово.

И не нужно никаких замен br, div и прочего парсинга

```
//selector1 - наш элемент с contenteditable
function get_text(selector1){
    let text_temp = document.querySelector(selector1);
    var el = text_temp;
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);

    if (window.getSelection()) {
        var select = window.getSelection();
        text_temp = select.toString();
    }
    
    console.log(text_temp);
    return text_temp;
}
```